# Memory visibility semantics of jni c native data when synchronized externally in java

Tags: java, c++, c, synchronization, java-native-interface

Basically we have a native method in java which is invoked through jni . THe java wrapper code is synchronizing on a java object before calling the native method. Inside the native method we have a pre-allocated array of c structures , which is getting resized through realloc .This array of c structures stays outside the jvm heap. Question is if i have another thread which is synchronizing in java on the same java object and calling another native method through jni , is it guaranteed that it will see a consistent view of the re allocated array of c structures . Assuming the c structure fields are not volatile .. Basically will the memory visibility semantics of Java synchronized block percolate to native allocated data if it is not part of the jvm heap . I am asking for redhat 4 and jdk1.6_30 64 bit.

Comment: No.  I would think the only thing that would "percolate" would be execution flow of threads.  So either your C code and memory usage will need to either be thread safe, or Java will need to ensure that only one thread is running a relevant native method at any given time.  And your data which may be accessed from distinct threads *will* need to be accessed in a volatile fashion, regardless of temporal locking, as volatile is used to prevent *compiler optimizations* incompatible with access not visible to the compiler.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  He's stated that the Java Wrapper function is synchronizing on a Java object before calling the native thread, so the Java layer is ensuring the thread-safeness.

Comment: And they asked "will the memory visibility semantics of Java synchronized block percolate to native allocated data" to which the answer is no - only execution flow "percolates".  And even where that is ensured, volatile is also needed if access which the compiler cannot anticipate when contemplating optimizations may occur.